# How to use URL parameter and page callbacks for tab menus correctly?

Tags: 6, routes

I'm using Drupal 6 and I'm trying to display two tab (menus) on a page that has the URL /vehicle_info.
Both pages that the tabs link to should take a node's nid as parameter.
My current code looks as follows:

```
  $items['vehicle_info/%/basic'] = array(
    'title' => t('Basic & Bookings'),
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('administer fleet'),
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 10
   );
  $items['vehicle_info/%/history'] = array(
    'title' => t('Service history'),
    'page callback' => 'vehicle_service_history',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('administer fleet'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 20
   );
```

I'm running into 2 issues:

1. The tab "Service history" does not open the page "vehicle_service_history" (which is actually a view with the URL vehicle_service_history). It opens a page with the URL
   "vehicle_info/123/history", which does not exist (123 stands for the current nid).
2. The default tab "Basic & Bookings" does not link to the URL "vehicle_info/123" but only to "vehicle_info".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things seem to be missing here. The main confusion seems to be around `page callback` which should be a **function** not a URL. The URL is the key to your `$items` array.

1. Your first menu item has no 'page callback'. This would be inherited from the parent item (keyed as `$items['vehicle_info/%']` and a type of `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM`) if you had one, but you don't.
2. Your second item menu seems to be confusing URL with callback as well. If you want it handled by a view then your page display on your view should handle the URL path `vehicle_info/%/history`, i.e. it will have a contextual filter. Does your view work like this?

Answer (score 0):

If vehicles is a content type that happens to sit under the path 'vehicle_info' then you can simplify this a lot. Enhance the regular core tabs

```
$items['node/%node/basic'] = array(
  'title' => t('Basic & Bookings'),
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access callback' => 'vehicle_administer_fleet',
  'access arguments' => array(1),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'weight' => 10
);
$items['node/%node/history'] = array(
  'title' => t('Service history'),
  'page callback' => 'vehicle_service_history',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access callback' => 'vehicle_administer_fleet',
  'access arguments' => array(1),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'weight' => 20
);
```

You will also need to define the custom access callback

```
function vehicle_administer_fleet($node) {
  return $node->type == 'vehicle' && user_access('administer fleet');
}
```

This is what drupal core does for it's own node tabs, more often then not, it is best to keep consistancy

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to try this but I'm not sure what you mean by "If vehicles is a content type that happens to sit under the path 'vehicle_info'". How can you set that a content type sits under a path?

Answer (score 0):

You went wrong way!!!
you can achieve completely what you want with  views.

Create A views ,add your field as you want , set page Url to `node/*/basic`, in view **Menu** section (below page url) select menu tab with you title([see this](http://www.wdtutorials.com/drupal/tabs/how-to-create-tabs-views-drupal-tutorial#.V0rag2bzK8U) for more info about create menu tab with views ).
Also in **Access** section you can select who can see this page created by views.

I think you really don't Know how powerful really views is ;).